# Java append to end of ArrayList in function

Tags: java, android, arraylist

with this below function i can create `ArrayList` and append any value into that. this action is not problem but after calling that every time i can not append to end of `ArrayList` without clear current values of that. after each call `ArrayList` clear.

```
public List<ReceiveFields> getReceivedSMS(long idToDown, long count) throws TException {

    .
    .
    .

    String str = WSDLHelper.call(request);

    String[] strings = WSDLHelper.convert2(WSDLHelper.convert1(str));

    List<ReceiveFields> receiveArray = new ArrayList<ReceiveFields>();

    if (strings != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= strings.length - 1; i++) {

            String[] str1 = WSDLHelper.convert3(strings[i]);

            try {

                receiveArray.add(new ReceiveFields(
                        Long.valueOf(str1[0]),

                        str1[1],

                        str1[2],

                        URLDecoder.decode(str1[3], "UTF-8"),

                        URLDecoder.decode(str1[4], "UTF-8"),

                        WSDLHelper.convertDate(str1[5])));

            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

                throw new TException(PublicErrorList.NOT_EXIST_ERROR_DETAIL);

            }
        }
    }
    return receiveArray;
}
```

Comment: Please explain more what your problem is.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are not sending any reference of the ArrayList to the function. Each time it creates a new list, resulting in losing previous values.

Comment: @TuxWorld do you want to have the values added to your receiveArray with repeated method calls to getReceivedSMS . If yes then declare your receiveArray as instance variable outside your method

Comment: define outside of method (receiveArray)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ReceiveFields> allReceiveFields = new ArrayList<>();
...
List<REceiveFields> addition = getReceivedSMS(idToDown, count);
allReceiveFields.addAll(addition);
```

Or

```
public void addReceivedSMS(List<ReceiveFields> receiveArray,
        long idToDown, long count) throws TException {


List<ReceiveFields> allReceiveFields = new ArrayList<>();

addReceivedSMS(allReceiveFields , idToDown, count);
```

---

***After feedback in comment:***

```
private List<ReceiveFields> rows = new ArrayList<>(); // Was not initialized

private void getR...SMS(...) {
    tsms = new ...;
    try {
        List<ReceiveFields> additions = tsms.getReceivedSMS(start, count);
        if (!additions.isEmpty()) { // Maybe extra check
            rows.addAll(additions);
            getLastReceivedSMSID = rows.get(rows.size() - 1).getLastId();
    ...
```

Comment: i can not use your method. please see this screen shot: http://rupload.ir/upload/e2jnl45jdo8ctcqwtbv.jpeg. UPDATED SCREEN SHOT

Comment: You already had a variable (`rows`) for that purpose. The `new ArrayList` is even immediately thrown away as you assign rows to the variable. I have added the now smaller code. _Thanks for the effort making a screenshot._

Comment: dont resolve problem sir .this link is my full code: http://pastebin.com/z12cPae5

Comment: excuse me i'm forget to paste error: `at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ir.tsms.Receive.ResivedSMS.getResivedSMS(ResivedSMS.java:58)`

Comment: Ah, `rows` was not initialized. You could do it in the constructor too.

Comment: i'm sorry i dont underestand it. define as `List<ReceiveFields> rows = new ArrayList<ReceiveFields>();` in constructor? or `rows = tsms.getReceivedSMS(start, count);`

Comment: In the construct `rows = new ArrayList<>();` - or as I wrote above, doing `= new ArrayList<>()` at the field declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will tell you why it does not work

```
public List<String> addItem(String temp) {
     ArrayList<String> listS = new ArrayList<>();
     listS.add(temp);
     return listS;
}
```

and how it will work

```
ArrayList<String> listS = new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> addItem(String temp) {         
     listS.add(temp);
     return listS;
}
```

Sorry for the quick coding, but the answer to your question is just that :)

Comment: A) where is the arraylist mentioned in the question? B) `new` is a keyword in Java. Don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer has anything to do with the question

Comment: I editted the answer to fit this question. The point is that his list is resetted, because its local and gets recreated everytime his method gets called.